# Organize node file attachments into groups

Tags: nodes, files

I have a content type with multiple file attachments to download. Is there a module to give authors the ability to divide all the attachments into groups, writing a title for every group, just like they can reorder and name them in edit mode?
The final node display should be something like this:

```
Group Title 1
. File n.1
Group Title 2
. File n.2
. File n.3
```

I've been searching for a while and found [FileTree](https://drupal.org/project/filetree), but it's too complicated. Files shouldn't be managed physically, just displayed in groups.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Field group](http://drupal.org/project/field_group) module. Create multi-value field group, with single-value *Group title* sub-field and multi-value *File* field inside. That's pretty much all.

Comment: I'm trying, but surely I do something wrong. I installed Field group and Field group multiple, created a Multiple fields container with a single text field and a multiple file field in it, but it doesn't work. All the files aren't shown on node page. Is there a documentation or a tutorial to read and understand where I go wrong?